# why base pointer value is stored in the stack

Tags: c++, c, compilation

From this site:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/
I saw that this program stack:

```
int foobar(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int xx = a + 2;
    int yy = b + 3;
    int zz = c + 4;
    int sum = xx + yy + zz;

    return xx * yy * zz + sum;
}

int main()
{
    return foobar(77, 88, 99);
}
```

in memory looks like in the following image:

[image]

I don't understand why the base pointer takes memory from the stack, could not it be just stored in a register like the stack pointer, just pointing where he needs? (I understood that the base pointer is used to find variables easier when the stackpointer makes push and pops, but I don't understand why its value is stored in the stack, not just in a register!  ), thanks a lot for your help (I'm afraid I'm missing something very important)

EDIT:
may be this helps more my confusion:  In the image they show 'EBP' (the register), and 'saved ebp'. I don't understand why there are two...

Comment: Why the return address have to be stored on the stack, not just in a register?

Comment: I understand that the basepointer has already a register EBP, but the return address does not have one. In the image they show 'EBP' (the register), and 'saved ebp'. I don't understand why there are two...

Comment: The base/frame pointer works like a linked list; EBP points to the current base pointer, the current base pointer points to the previous base pointer, and so on.

Comment: The return address certainly has a register where it lives before and after the call, namely the program counter (PC) or instruction pointer (IP) -- the name varies by architecture.  Unless you're doing some continuation-oriented calling, the return address is nothing more than "saved program counter", which helps execution resume in the caller when the called function returns.

Comment: @Melak47 that makes a lot of sense... if you have time to put it in an answer  I think I should vote you up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should realize that this style of stack frame is no longer really necessary. Most current compilers can (and do) eliminate saving [E]BP on the stack, and copying [E]SP to [E]BP on entry to a function. At one time (16-bit code) this was needed because BP could act as a base register, but SP could not. That meant you couldn't do thing like `-7[SP]`, but you could do `-7[BP]`. As of the 386 and 32-bit code, however, that was no longer the case--you can use ESP (or any other register) as a base register.

There is still some reason to save EBP on entry to a procedure/function though: unless the stack gets corrupted, it's really easy to walk. EBP points to the previous value of EBP, which points to the previous value, and so on all the way down the stack. If you're debugging (for example) this makes it quite easy to do a stack trace. If you have to walk through some code for which you have no symbols, you can walk across them, find earlier stack frames you do understand, and examine them in detail.

By contrast, if you use ESP directly, it gets adjusted on entry to a function to make space for that function's local variables. You need to know how much it was adjusted by to get back to the previous stack frame. If you get to a point for which you have no information, and you don't know how much ESP was adjusted on entry to that function, you're pretty much stuck (short of disassembling the code to find the stack adjustment so you can un-do it).

Answer (score 1):

So that the stack pointer can be incremented to accomodate the new stack frame. When it is time to return, the base pointer is popped into the stack pointer to restore the old value.

You can't assume there are any registers at all, let alone spare registers, and to dedicate a register to something that is certainly not going to be used until the function exits would be a waste of a precious resource.